# My php file is not working either in localhost or on my webhost, is something wrong with my mysql_connect?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

My php file is not working either in localhost or on my webhost, is something wrong with my mysql_connect?

```
still not fixed, this is what I did base on your reply:

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

//first get the post variables on the page
$region=$_POST['region'];
$province_of_provider=$_POST['province_of_provider'];

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','gengon4_tesda','gengon4_tesda','gengon4_tesda');
if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}

//mysql_select_db('gengon4_tesda',$con);

$query="INSERT INTO `details` (`id`, `date_of_entry`, `region`, `province_of_provider`) VALUES (NULL, 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6).000000', '$region', '$province_of_provider')";

if(!mysql_query($query,$con))
{
    die('Error in inserting records'.mysql_error);
}else
{
    echo "Data Inserted";
}

echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";

?>
```

I did not find any info about the error. Any idea how to address this problem?

Comment: turn on php errors and check out error logs

Comment: still not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly Enable the display_errors in your php.ini as `display_errors = On` or set it in your php file as `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` 
By this way you should know what's wrong in your code.

**Modifications in code:**

`$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','gengon4_tesda','gengon4_tesda','gengon4_tesda');`

you used `mysqli_connect` to connecting database and here in '`if(!mysql_query($query,$con))`' mysql_query to running query.
Please make sure to use same methods either **mysqli** or **mysql** all over in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont use `mysql_*` functions. Always use `mysqli_*` functions.
2. enable show errors by command: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` (first line of your source code)
3. then show errors by: `echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";` (mysqli_*)
4. then you will se whats wrong